# getting a error 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

want to count the number of occurrence to be true which is
satisfying below condition ,but it not showing the value in true or
false but not able to count it,I don't know where i am doing wrong please have a look into my below code

```
            from openpyxl import load_workbook
            import openpyxl as xl 
            from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
            import pandas as pd
            import os
            import xlwings as xw
            import datetime
            
            filelist_patch=[f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".xlsx") and 'SEL' in f.upper() and '~' not in f.upper()]
            print(filelist_patch[0])
            wb = xl.load_workbook(filelist_patch[0],read_only=True,data_only=True)
            wb_device=wb["de_exp"]
            
            cols_device = [0,9,14,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25]
            #######################average count in vuln##############################
            for row in wb_device.iter_rows(max_col=25):
                cells = [cell.value for (idx, cell) in enumerate(row) if (
                         idx in cols_device and cell.value is not None)]
              
              
                os_de=cells[1]
                qca_de=cells[2]
               
  
            
        
                file_data =((os_de=="cl") & (qca_de=='Q'))
                print(sum(file_data))
```

getting a type error

```
 TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-70-735a490062da> in <module>
     
         30     file_data =((os_de=="client") & (qca_de=='Q'))(here i want to count the number of occurence that is in true
    ---> 31     print(sum(file_data))
         32 
         33 

    TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: This question was very hard to read. please provide more details about what you are trying to do and how we can replicate it. Your error looks like it is coming from code you don't even have in your post. And you want to count the number of occurrences in true? True is a boolean and you can't iterate over a boolean. Do you mean you want to count how many occurrences are true where  (os_de=="client") & (qca_de=='Q'). You also don't have your code for this posted now

Comment: apologies ,yes i want to  count how many occurrences are true where (os_de=="client") & (qca_de=='Q').

Comment: updated the code in the edits

Comment: I dont get why use python if this kind of check can be done with simple function in excel itself, are there any cases which the excel + VBA doesn't cover ?

Comment: anything on this still struggling to count the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to read. Please use proper grammar and punctuation. I understand that you are probably not a native speaker, but that is no excuse to not form proper sentences that start with a capital letter and end with a period.

Please sort your own thoughts before you ask a question, and then write your thoughts in *multiple* short an concise sentenses.

Nonetheless, I'll try to *guess* what you are trying to say.

90% of your code is unrelated to the question, so I'll try to reform your question. If my guess is incorrect, of course my answer will be worthless, and I'd ask you to reword your question to be more precise.

---

### Reworded Question

**Question:** How to count the number of *true* statements in a number of conditions?

**Details:** Given a number of conditions (like `os_de=="client"` and `qca_de=='Q'`), how do I count the number of correct ones among them?

**Attempt:**

```py
# Dummy data, to make this a short and reproducable example:
cells = ["", "cl", "D"]
os_de = cells[1]
qca_de = cells[2]
file_data = ((os_de=="cl") & (qca_de=='Q'))
print(sum(file_data))
```

**Expected result value:** `1`

**Actual result:**

```
 TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-70-735a490062da> in <module>
     
         30     file_data = ((os_de=="client") & (qca_de=='Q'))
    ---> 31     print(sum(file_data))
         32 
         33 

    TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

---

### Answer

Both `(os_de=="client")` and `(qca_de=='Q')` are of type `boolean`.
Using `&` on them makes the result still be a `boolean`. So if you try to use `sum()` on it, it rightfully complains that the sum of a boolean does not make sense.

Sum can only be done over a collection of numbers.

You are almost there, though. Just instead of combining them with `&`, make them a list instead.

```
# Dummy data, to make this a short and reproducable example:
cells = ["", "cl", "D"]
os_de = cells[1]
qca_de = cells[2]
file_data = [(os_de=="cl"), (qca_de=='Q')]
print(sum(file_data))
```

Which prints `1`, as expected: https://ideone.com/96Rghq

Try to include an ideone.com link in your questions in the future, this forces you to make your example code complete, simple and reproducable.